# ReactJS - Can't import QueryBuilder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just getting started with ReactJS. I'm trying to load [react-query-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-querybuilder) into my component. When I simply add `import {QueryBuilder} from 'react-querybuilder'`, I get an error in the console

> index.js:29852 Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined

Here is the initial working code

```
// index.html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">                                                                          
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Should see the rule builder...</p>
      <div id="rule-builder"></div>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
      <p>After the rule builder...</p>
   </body>
</html>

// main.js
import React from 'react';                                                                            
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';                                                                     
import RuleBuilder from './RuleBuilder.jsx';                                                          

ReactDOM.render(<RuleBuilder/>, document.getElementById('rule-builder'));

// RuleBuilder.js
import React from 'react';

class RuleBuilder extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Rule Builder</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default RuleBuilder;
```

The page renders

```
Should see the rule builder...

Rule Builder

After the rule builder...
```

But as soon as I add `import {QueryBuilder} from 'react-querybuilder'` the aforementioned error appears and the 'Rule Builder' output on the page disappears so the ReactComponent no longer renders.

What am I doing wrong?

(PS Here are package.json & webpack.config.js)

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "react-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing out the ReactJS library",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 192.168.56.152 --port 5001 --hot",
    "build": "babel ./ --presets babel-preset-es2015 --out-dir distribution"
  },  
  "author": "", 
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-querybuilder": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },  
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-querybuilder": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}

// webpack.config.js
var config = { 
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },  

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080,
      hot: true
   },  

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {   
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }   
         }   
      ]   
   }   
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Can you try requiring `QueryBuilder` and see if it works?

Comment: try adding react source as a global var via script tag `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js`, author is using `externals` webpack option for their dist build

Comment: @Daniel How do I tell it to include react with the dist build? Currently I'm building with `webpack --progress -p`, however when I run `babel ./ --presets babel-preset-es2015 --out-dir distribution` it complains about JSX _SyntaxError: RuleBuilder.jsx: Unexpected token (21:9)_

Comment: the dist build uses `externals` in its webpack config. it looks like `react` is assumed to be a global. https://github.com/sapientglobalmarkets/react-querybuilder/blob/master/dist/index.js#L71

Comment: @Daniel_L I see, thanks for the link. I added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom-server.js"></script>` as the first tag inside the body, yet the error persists.

Comment: @HardikModha Adding `var React = require('react');` did not have any effect. The error message is the same as before.

Comment: I tried using [react-create-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and encountered the same problem. I've opened [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sapientglobalmarkets/react-querybuilder/issues/20).

Comment: Just updating - the aforementioned bug was valid and a fix was submitted to fix the library.